# xslt formatting numbers

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0, number-formatting

I need to format decimals values in xslt. The template should remove the decimal. And show the number of specified who numbers followed bythe specified decimal positions. The round template round the decimal. When I try to use my current templates I get NaN.

the template should convert 992.45 to 000000992 if digitCount= 9

```
<xsl:template name="RoundedDecimalFormat">
    <xsl:param name="num"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="digitCount"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:variable name="value" select="format-number(round($num), '#########')"></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:call-template name="format-batchnum">
      <xsl:with-param name="batchnum" select="$value"></xsl:with-param>
      <xsl:with-param name="numbatchdigit" select="$digitCount"></xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>
```

template below should convert 1323.91 to 00000132391 if manyDigits = 9

```
 <xsl:template name="UnRoundedDecimalFormat">
    <xsl:param name="time"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="manyDigits"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:variable name="value" select="format-number($time, '#########')"></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:call-template name="format-batchnum">
      <xsl:with-param name="batchnum" select="$value"></xsl:with-param>
      <xsl:with-param name="numbatchdigit" select="$manyDigits"></xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>
```

this part works fine i use elsewhere

```
<xsl:template name="format-batchnum">
    <xsl:param name="batchnum"/>
    <xsl:param name="numbatchdigit"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(substring($vZeroes,1,$numbatchdigit), string-length($batchnum) +1), $batchnum)"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

***UPDATED****

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" 
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
                xmlns:ns0="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/02/xpath-functions " 
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
                version="2.0">


 <xsl:call-template name="UnRoundedDecimalFormat">
      <xsl:with-param name="salary" select="$annualSalary"></xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>


<xsl:template name="RoundedDecimalFormat">
    <xsl:param name="num"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="digitCount" select ="9"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:variable name="value" select="format-number(round($num), '#########')"></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:call-template name="format-batchnum">
      <xsl:with-param name="batchnum" select="$value"></xsl:with-param>
      <xsl:with-param name="numbatchdigit" select="$digitCount"></xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="UnRoundedDecimalFormat">
    <xsl:param name="time"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="manyDigits" select ="9"></xsl:param>

    <xsl:variable name="vTime" select="translate(string($time), '.', '')"/>

    <xsl:variable name="value" select="format-number(number(xs:string($vTime)), '#########')"></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:call-template name="format-batchnum">
      <xsl:with-param name="batchnum" select="$value"></xsl:with-param>
      <xsl:with-param name="numbatchdigit" select="$manyDigits"></xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
 </xsl:template>


function roundedDecimalFormat(number){
try{
var n = Math.round(number);
return n;}
catch(err){return '';}
}

function removeDecimal(number){
try{
var n = number.replace('.','');
return n;}
catch(err){
return '';
}
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just a slight touch to your code makes it work as desired:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vZeroes" select=
    "'0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:call-template name="RoundedDecimalFormat">
      <xsl:with-param name="num" select="992.45"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="digitCount" select="9"/>
     </xsl:call-template>
=========================
     <xsl:call-template name="UnRoundedDecimalFormat">
      <xsl:with-param name="time" select="1323.91"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="manyDigits" select="9"/>
     </xsl:call-template>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="RoundedDecimalFormat">
    <xsl:param name="num"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="digitCount"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:variable name="value" select="format-number(round($num), '#########')"></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:call-template name="format-batchnum">
      <xsl:with-param name="batchnum" select="$value"></xsl:with-param>
      <xsl:with-param name="numbatchdigit" select="$digitCount"></xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="UnRoundedDecimalFormat">
    <xsl:param name="time"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="manyDigits"></xsl:param>

    <xsl:variable name="vTime" select="translate(string($time), '.', '')"/>

    <xsl:variable name="value" select="format-number(number(xs:string($vTime)), '#########')"></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:call-template name="format-batchnum">
      <xsl:with-param name="batchnum" select="$value"></xsl:with-param>
      <xsl:with-param name="numbatchdigit" select="$manyDigits"></xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="format-batchnum">
    <xsl:param name="batchnum"/>
    <xsl:param name="numbatchdigit"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(substring($vZeroes,1,$numbatchdigit), string-length($batchnum) +1), $batchnum)"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on any XML document (not used), the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
000000992
=========================
000132391
```

Comment: Thanks I will give a shot when I get to office tommorow!

Comment: I get this error when trying to debug.  Cannot find a script or an extension object associated with namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'.   It's coming from,  <xsl:variable name="value" select="format-number(number(xs:string($vTime)), '#########')"></xsl:variable>, any idea why? thanks

Comment: @Rufio, This code (as all my code in SO answers) is tested and verified to work. If you just copy and paste it and run the transformation it *must* work. If you copied and pasted only fragments of this code, then most probably your code misses the namespace declaration for the XSD namespace -- you must have such namespace declaration that binds a "xs" prefix to the "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" namespace-uri.

Comment: Would <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/> have something to do with it?

Comment: @Rufio, No. Are you sure you are performing the transformation with an XSLT 2.0 processor?

Comment: @Rufio, One immediate error is that you are referring to a undefined variable `$annualSalary`. You must correct this.

Comment: $annualSalary is a param in a template that is calling UnroundedDecimalFormat. The actual value, AnnualSalary in the xml does not exist yet, could this cause it to fail?

Comment: @Rufio, Yes, a reference to undefined variable always is an error.

Comment: Thanks I was assuming it would just provide a empty string.

Comment: I just went the jscript above since they can't get me the xml fast enough! Thanks for help

Comment: @Rufio, You can just make `$annualSalary` a global `xsl:param` with default value the empty string -- then the error is eliminated: `<xsl:param name="annualSalary" select="''"/>`